# html2canvas + toDataUrl + ajax, getting blank files

Tags: ajax, loops, for-loop, canvas, html2canvas

I need to generate various canvas using html2canvas, and then pass them using ajax so I can create a new file for each canvas.
What's the problem?

The files are empty (but they weight 300kb aprox)

A quick explanation for the code:

-generarImagenBuena() is called when you click a button.

-There is a for loop that sorts through a list of ids... it enters into GenerateImage to generate each image (most important part)

this is the code:

```
function generarImagenBuena() {

    //Oculta los controles
    $('.controles').hide();
    $('.eliminar').hide();

    //Oculta los bloques sin sub-bloques
    $('.bloque').each(function(i,v)
    {
        if ($(v).find('tr').length==0) //Si este bloque no tiene filas, lo oculta...
        {
            $(v).hide();
        }
    });

    $('.wrapper').css({'zoom':'calc(5.38)'});

    for(var h = 0; h < elements.length; h++)
        GenerateImage(h);

    $('.wrapper').css({'zoom':'calc(1/5.38)'});

    //Vuelve a mostrar los controles
    $('.controles').show();
    $('.eliminar').show();
    $('.bloque').show();

}

function GenerateImage(ii)
{

console.log(elements[ii]);
    //Genera la imagen y la guarda en un archivo
    html2canvas($(elements[ii]), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;

            // Convert and download as image 
            //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);

            myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 

            $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: 'SaveImage.php',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        base64data : myImage,
                        num : ii
                    },
                    success:function(r)
                    {
                        console.log(r);
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        console.log('Falló el ajax, presione Control+F5');
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you only do one single id?

Comment: Sorry for this, the problem is the natural async of ajax, I'm working on a solution and I'm going to post it here when it's done!